# How to create variable from piped data

Tags: ls, command-substitution, variable-substitution, wc

The command I using is: `ls -l . | totLines=$(wc -l) echo $totLines` . My goal is display the total number of lines, but by assigning the output of `wc -l` a variable name, then displaying that variable's value. However this is not working. HOw can I create a variable out of the output from `wc -l` after it has obtained the lines it's processing from a previous `ls` command?

Comment: Don't parse `ls` except for your own eyes. In scripts you'd rather do `count=(*); printf 'There are %d in total' "${#count[@]}"`

Answer (score 2):

Your pipe is not going to your inner shell in that case, so you would want to

```
totLines=$(ls -l . | wc -l)
printf '%s\n' "$totLines"
```

to do what you're trying here.  The `-l .` part don't really make much of a difference in this case though, so you could leave them off.  Also, beware that if any of your filenames contain a new line you'd get the wrong count this way.

Comment: Cool, another quick question. How can I then create another variable that contains computation the previous variable with some mathematical changes: `totLines=$(ls -l . | wc -l) | final=$(($totLines-1)) | echo $final` . It seems that the pipe only sends STDOUT by itself, but does not actually send the Variable with it's value. I am able to achieve this in a Script since the script saves the variable with it's value consistently. How cold I achieve this through one command with the CLI?

Comment: Another piece of advice. Don't use `ls -l` for whatever you are trying to do. What is your final goal in this adventure?  `ls -l` is just doomed to fail.

Comment: @user42076 right, the pipe sends stdout from the left process to the right process, that's what it does.  If you want to run one command then the next you can just put `;` between them.  But as val0x00ff asked, what are you actually trying to do here?  Parsing `ls` output is usually the wrong thing to do. . .

Comment: @val0x00ff & Eric,, my final goal was just playing and learning more about variables and one line commands :) I appreciate the help and advice guys :)

Comment: @user42076 alright then.  A pipe just connects stdout from the left to stdin on the right, and it runs them in subshells so you cannot alter variables in the parent environment, so mixing pipes and variable assignments is often the path to frustration

Comment: Yea, makes. I think it's best to use command substitution if planning to use a pipe.